# How can I ensure the event handlers for my blazor form button elements run

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am including some blazor web assembly components in a large razor pages project.
I have added a blazor web assembly project to the solution and included the components on the razor page with this code:

```
<component type="typeof(NewProcessForm)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered"/>
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
```

When I added the Counter component or any other component the page renders just fine but I have tried many variations within a form and I cannot capture an onclick event

```
<span id="newreference">@(NewReference)</span>
<EditForm Model="@(process)" OnSubmit="@(AddNew)">
  <button id="getref" type="submit" @onclick="@(()=>GetNewReference("new"))">Get a New Reference</button>
  <textarea id="newprocess"></textarea>
  <button id="addprocess" type="submit" @onclick="@(()=>AddNewProcess())">Add the New Process</button>
</EditForm>
@(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss FFF"))

@code
{
  private string NewReference

  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
   NewReference = "No new reference.";
  }

  public void GetNewReference()
  {
   IReferences ref = new References();
   NewReference = ref.GetReference(new);
   //InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
  }

  public void AddNew()
  {
   IProcess proc = new Process();
   proc.AddNew();
   NewReference = "New process added.";
  }
 }
```

I have tried the buttons as `type="button"`, without using an `EditForm` tag, with various formats for the onclick directive, all together and in different arrangements of them.
This version refreshes the page whenever either button is clicked and the Time display updates but none of the breakpoints in the @code section methods ever get hit.
I am new to blazor and new to stackoverflow but I have seen questions people don't think are any good.
If mine is not good please let me know so I can change it.

UPDATE

I have edited the mark up based on @MrC aka Shaun Curtis 's fine answer but the breakpoints in the methods are still not being hit.

```
<span id="newreference">@(NewReference)</span>
  <button id="getref" @(onclick=GetNewReference("new"))>Get a New Reference</button>
  <textarea id="newprocess"></textarea>
  <button id="addprocess" @(onclick=AddNewProcess())>Add the New Process</button>
</EditForm>
@(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss FFF"))
```

Comment: Are you sure your Web Assembly code is running in Debug mode i.e. your VS debug environment is set up correctly?   Add a line like "I've run" to your button handlers and display it on the page.  If the DateTime refreshes then it would appear that the event code is running.   You need  "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}", in the launchSettings.json in both the WASM and Web Server projects

Comment: The datetime string is to demonstrate the web code is running.
The 'inspecturi' attribute is present twice in each launchsettings.json file under both IIS Express and the razor pages project or wasm project respectively.
I have been assuming I have written the attributes in the tag elements wronglty?
This is a good point and I think I should up vote it, as soon as I have the permission to.

Comment: If you are still having problems, try preparing a sample here: https://blazorfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're so very nearly there.
I know what it's like trying to ask the right question on stackoverflow and this took me a long time to get right.
As you want two buttons to do different things, add the form submission to the correct event handler.
Also, to get data out of a form, this has the model `MyAwesomeProcessModel` to put the input fields into

```
<span id="newreference">@(NewReference)</span>
<EditForm Model="@(process)">
  <button id="getref" type="submit" @onclick="@(e => GetNewReference("new"))">Get a New Reference</button>
  <textarea @bind=@(process.whatevermyawesomeeprocessespropertyis)></textarea>
  <button id="addprocess" type="submit" @onclick=AddNewProcess>Add the New Process</button>
</EditForm>
@(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss FFF"))

@code
{
     private MyAwesomeProcessModel process;
     private string NewReference;    

     protected override void OnInitialized()
     {
      NewReference = "No new reference.";
     }

     protected override bool ShouldRender()
     {
      return false;
     }

     public void GetNewReference()
     {
      IReferences ref = new References();
      NewReference = ref.GetReference(new);
     }

     public void AddNewProcess()
     {
      IProcess proc = new Process();
      proc.AddNew(process.whatevermyawesomeeprocessespropertyis);
      NewReference = "New process added.";
     }
}
```

Also, returning `false` from the `ShouldRender` method stops the page refresh.

Comment: This worked great and the shouldrender override was something I didn't know I needed.
For other people finding this answer, the onclick can use just the name of the object for argumentless methods but the arrow thing if an argument is required,

Answer (score 0):

Back to Basics code.

1. Does the counter increment on a button click?
2. Do you hit the breakpoint?

```
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.ButtonClick>Click to Update Counter</button>
</div>
<div class="m-2">
    Counter: @_counter
</div>

@code {
    private int _counter = 1;

    private void ButtonClick()
    {
        // Breakpoint here - Do you hit it?
        _counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This button works:

```
<button @onclick="@(() => onButtonClick(true))">Click Me</button>

@if (wasTrue)
{
    <h1>Made true</h1>
}

@code {

    bool wasTrue = false;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
    }

    public void onButtonClick(bool myBool)
    {
        wasTrue = true;
    }
}
```